# Delete records from more than 1 year ago

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm saving twitter tweets in my database with spring JPA Repositories. The date of the tweet is saved as Datetime in the MySQL db. Now I want to delete all tweets that are older than one year. I saw there is the function `CURRENT_TIME` and I thought of something like `CURRENT_TIME - 360`. I know thats not the correct syntax but I have no idea how to do this. Here is what I have:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("DELETE FROM Tweetpost t WHERE t.createdAt > ")
int removeOlderThan();
```

**EDIT SOLVED:**

Repository:

```
@Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("DELETE FROM Tweetpost m WHERE m.createdAt < :date")
    int removeOlderThan(@Param("date") java.sql.Date date);
```

Service:

```
public void removeOldItems() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -360);

        java.sql.Date oneYear = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

        tweetRepository.removeOlderThan(oneYear);


    }
```

Comment: `WHEREt.createdAt < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR`

Comment: So why is this tagged mysql?

Comment: Because its a mysql db working in the background.

Comment: But you can't pass raw (my)sql to it?

Comment: Not with Spring JPA Data, it throws an exception when I use "Interval".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For this you need 2 steps. First of all you need a method that will take as a parameter the date of which you want to delete the messages and you dont need tha `@Query` annotation at all.

So in your repository you must have something like

```
    @Modifying
    public void deleteByCreatedAtBefore(Date expiryDate);
```

Now in your service method, you will calculate the Date and pass it on like this

```
    public void performTweetCleanup(){
       //calculate date
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       Date today = cal.getTime();
       cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
       Date previousYear = cal.getTime();

       //call the method
       MyTweeterRepository.deleteByCreatedAtBefore(previousYear);
     }
```

Comment: When I add this to the Repo it says: `Invalid derived query! No property deleteTweetstbyCreatedAt found for type Tweetpost!`

Comment: No problem I worked with your Example and solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks mate best of luck with spring data :)

Comment: `@Modifying` does nothing when used with a query derived from the method name; it only matters when using `@Query`. Also doing it this way will cause JPA to load your entities rather than just delete them which can cause a huge performance loss or just fail altogether.

Answer (score 6):

**SOLVED:**

Repository:

```
@Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("DELETE FROM Tweetpost m WHERE m.createdAt < :date")
    int removeOlderThan(@Param("date") java.sql.Date date);
```

Service:

```
public void removeOldItems() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -360);

        java.sql.Date oneYear = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());

        tweetRepository.removeOlderThan(oneYear);


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Compute the current time minus one year in Java, and then use the follwoing query:

```
DELETE FROM Tweetpost t WHERE t.createdAt < :nowMinusOneYear
```

Comment: I already tried to compute a newDate - 360 days but it allways gives me an error..

Comment: How could we possibly help you if you don't post the code used to compute it and the error you got?

Comment: yes sorry here is what I have but there are alot of syntax errors when I try to create the new date "OneYear"...                                            `Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime(dateInstance);
 cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -360);
 Date OneYear = cal.getTime();`

Comment: Post that in the question, and tell what the error is.

Comment: I did is it possible, that i can't create new dates in the repository?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the current time you could use

```
System.getCurrentTimeMillis()
```

Take the time from the old date and subtract it from the current one then you just have to compare it with the duration of one year.
Maybe you should add something for leap-years.